# How to parse a huge XML file in Liferay with Java?

Tags: xml, parsing, liferay, sax, liferay-7

I have always been told that when parsing huge XML files, the memory-heavy DOM parsers should be avoid in favour of the lightweight SAX parsers.

I want to parse a huge XML file in Liferay. The file is just a list of items, and I need to process the items one-by-one independently, so it is a perfect use case for SAX.

I have found Liferay's [SAXReaderUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/xml/SAXReaderUtil.html), but despite the "SAX" in its name, it looks suspiciously like a DOM parser. It has no events, and it seems to be all about returning a Document and selecting nodes with XPath. Am I mistaken?

What is the correct way to parse a huge XML file when developing a Liferay module?

Comment: how big is your xml? there will be trade offs... sax or stax are much hard to code and have limited functionalities...

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: The XML file can be several gigabytes. Being hard to code is not a problem. I don't need much functionality, just get the elements from first to last in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing forcing you to utilize Liferay's XML Utils. Based on the way you're asking the question, I'm assuming that you're well experienced in parsing xml and its caveats. As a corollary I'm assuming that "you're doing it in Liferay like anywhere else" might be enough.

Ideally, the XML parser/processor that you're deciding for should come as an OSGi bundle (or you find one already deployed in Liferay).

Comment: Thanks! I have found that the easiest is to extend [org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) which is conveniently available with Java 7. This avoids adding a dependency.